# Can I use my brothers old SIM card that's in an iPad he gave me?

Tags: ipad, wifi, sim

My brother just gave me his old iPad after purchasing a new one. He accidently  left his SIM card in there because he got a different SIM card for his new one. I won't be able to add to my current carrier plan for another month or so, but when I turned on and activated the iPad in order to get to home screen, my wi-fi picked up and asked for my password. It is now working wth my wi-fi with no problems. I turned the carrier settings off, because I know the SIM card is still activated thru his account. My question is by only using wi-fi with his old SIM card, and leaving carrier data off, (until I transfer on my account) is there any chance at all he would be charged or notified it was being used, etc.?

Comment: Why not take the SIM card out

Answer (score 1):

If you leave the carrier OFF the card should actually not be charged. At least that's usually the recommendation when using an iPad abroad. As far as I know you could actually even remove the SIM card and still use the iPad over wifi – and maybe that would be the best option if you want to be 100% sure your brother's account is not charged.

Comment: Thank you... I will try to remove the SIM card and see what happens. I just got the ipad yesterday. I just assumed it wouldn't because I asked my brother if you can use a devise over wi-fi if it's not activated through my carrier and he said you couldn't, but I will try it without sim and see what happens. Thanks again

Comment: well – a.f.a.i.k. for iPhones this is true – but iPads work without SIM card inside

Comment: Very good news! Thanks for your help. Haven't got a chance to take it out yet and try it but will soon. It's a gift for my husband so i want to get it figured out before I give him. Thanks again